# How to simulate a Delphi breakpoint in code?

Tags: delphi, debugging, ide, breakpoints

I am pretty sure I have seen this before, but I haven't found out / remembered how to do it.  I want to have a line of code that when executed from the Delphi debugger I want the debugger to pop-up like there was a break point on that line.

Something like:

```
FooBar := Foo(Bar);
SimulateBreakPoint; // Cause break point to occur in Delphi IDE if attached
WriteLn('Value: ' + FooBar);
```

Hopefully that makes sense. I know I could use an exception, but that would be a lot more overhead then I want.  It is for some demonstration code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To trigger the debugger from code (supposedly, I don't have a copy of delphi handy to try):

```
asm int 3 end;
```

See this page:

http://17slon.com/blogs/gabr/2008/03/debugging-with-lazy-breakpoints.html

Comment: That was it.  Worked great!  Thanks!  Now I need to find a way to move up the call stack for the break point. . . .

Comment: Beware to catch EExternal else there will be an external exception while running outside of the debugger.

Comment: Or, as I suggested: if DebugHook <> 0 then asm int 3 end;

Comment: I'd usually do "if (DebugHook <> 0) and (**Break Condition**) then asm int 3 end;" so i'd add a condition to break, and put this code right before an error/bug in some conditions.

Answer (score 14):

As Andreas Hausladen stated in comments to that artice, Win32 API DebugBreak() function is  less DOS-ish and works equally well.

Comment: DebugBreak() puts the break point in the dissassembly/CPU window.  I'd rather have it in my code.