# C++ breakpoints are ignored / missed

Tags: c++, debugging, c++builder, breakpoints, c++builder-2010

I'm trying to run some C++ code someone gave me. At first there was a broken link to an `istream` file, which I fixed by adding the include path:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\7.0\include\dinkumware
```

The code now compiles but it doesn't stop at any breakpoints, for example those in the `formcreate`:

```
// Initialise the form and read in the module and inverter names.
void __fastcall TMain::FormCreate(TObject *Sender)
{
    ifstream inits;
    ifstream inverters;
    ifstream modules;
    char line[1000];
    AnsiString FTO;
    inits.open("PVSM.ini", ios::in);
    if (inits.is_open())
    {
            inits.getline(line,1000);
            AnsiString parmm(line);
            ModDir = parmm.SubString(1,parmm.Pos(" ")-1);
            inits.getline(line,1000);
            AnsiString parmi(line);
            InvDir = parmi.SubString(1,parmi.Pos(" ")-1);
            inits.getline(line,1000);
            AnsiString parmt(line);
            MetDir = parmt.SubString(1,parmt.Pos(" ")-1);
            inits.getline(line,1000);
            AnsiString parms(line);
            ShdDir = parms.SubString(1,parms.Pos(" ")-1);
            inits.getline(line,1000);
            AnsiString parmx(line);
            ExpDir = parmx.SubString(1,parmx.Pos(" ")-1);
    }
    else    // Should never get here, but if ini file missing use defaults
    {
        ModDir = "C://";
        InvDir = "C://";
        MetDir = "C://";
        ShdDir = "C://";
    }
    inits.close();
    FTO = InvDir + "inverters.data";
    inverters.open(FTO.c_str(), ios::in);
    if (inverters.is_open())
    {
            while ( inverters.getline(line,1000) )
            {
               AnsiString inverter(line);
               IVBox->Items->Add(inverter);
            }
    }
    inverters.close();
    FTO = ModDir + "modules.data";
    modules.open(FTO.c_str(), ios::in);
    if (modules.is_open())
    {
            while ( modules.getline(line,1000) )
            {
               AnsiString module(line);
               ModBox->Items->Add(module);
            }
    }
    modules.close();
    CMod = 1;
    CStr = 1;
    CCell = 1;
    nStore = 0;
    grid = true;
    pasan = false;
    debug = false;
    calc = false;
    cell = false;
    module = false;
    array1 = false;
    inv = false;
    PV = true;
    Parray = false;
    Pcurve = false;
    LastType = 'X';
    CurrTp = -1;  //* Not currently set
    AllSame = true;
    LdMeteo = false;
    mpp = true;
}
```

It just opens the form as if it was run from the `.exe` file, except it shows

> Compiling MyProject.cbproj (Release configuration).... Success

in the message bar

I've tried switching from release to debug mode, tried changing the output directories so it compiles new `.obj` files. No success.

I'm running `Rad studio 2010`,  it was originally written in `XE5`, but I think this is an issue with folder structure rather than IDE version?

Any suggestions?

Comment: In Release builds, many breakpoints _cannot_ be hit, because that code is inlined. Either debug a Debug build (or non-optimized Release, if that makes sense for your context), or set breakpoints at places that _cannot_ be inlined and step from there, or learn to read assembly and set breakpoints there.

Comment: The formcreate method is only called once and isn't marked inline. I can't imagine it would be automatically inlined by the compiler?

Comment: By "marking", I assume you mean _declare_ - if you _had_ declared it `inline`, it would still only be a _hint_ - the compiler almost always knows better than the developer when something ought to be inlined or not. That said, please paste the `formcreate` function and we'll most likely be able to tell if it is likely to be inlined or not.

Comment: Thanks Johann, I have added the code to the original question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some ideas (from various sources) that may or may not be useful to you:

- make sure that you're using the **Debug configuration** and do a **Build** of the project, not just a Compile: switching back to debug configuration and doing a compile after a release build isn't enough
- in your project options for Win32(Debug) make sure that the following options are set to the correct values

  - [C++ Compiler] → [Debugging] → [Debug information] `= True`;
  - [C++ Compiler] → [Debugging] → [Debug line number information] `= True`;
  - [C++ Compiler] → [Optimizations] → [Disable all optimizations] `= True`;
  - [C++ Compiler] → [Optimizations] → [Generate fastest possible code] `= False`;
  - [C++ Linker] → [Full Debug information] `= True`;
  - [Delphi Compiler] → [Optimization] `= False`;
  - [Delphi Compiler] → [Use debug .dcus] `= True`;

  (e.g. the [default configuration template](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=125682) for MDI application is wrong)
- delete all the `.pch`, `.#` and `.tds` files and let the compiler recreate
- if you are running the IDE under VirtualBox consider that some versions have problem with breakpoints (v4.3.x)

As a last resort you could try `{ _asm { int 3 } }` to [simulate a breakpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160923/how-to-simulate-a-delphi-breakpoint-in-code).

Also take a look at:

- [Quality Central](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?search=1&proj=15&kw=breakpoint)
- [Delphi: why breakpoints from time to time are not usable (green highlighted line on IDE)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679989/delphi-why-breakpoints-from-time-to-time-are-not-usable-green-highlighted-line)